# How to work with variables assigned in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server query:

```
DECLARE @comm decimal(12,2), 
        @amount decimal(12,2) 
SET @comm = 0

SELECT @amount = TotalAmount 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Id = 1

IF @amount > 25000
    @comm = 0.0005 * @amount;
ELSE
    @comm = 0
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@comm'.

I am trying to calculate a value as `@comm` as shown in the code. But I always get a syntax error near `@comm`. Can you please tell me why is that?

**AFTER INSERTING:**

```
DECLARE @comm decimal(12,2), 
        @amount decimal(12,2) 
SET @comm = 0;

SELECT @amount = TotalAmount 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Id = 1;

IF @amount > 25000
    @comm = 0.0005 * @amount;
Else
    @comm = 0;
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '@comm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expression :

```
SELECT @comm = (CASE WHEN TotalAmount > 25000 THEN TotalAmount * 0.0005 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Orders 
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Note : If `id = 1` has multiple matching rows then you need to use `top (1)` :

```
SELECT TOP (1) @comm = (CASE WHEN TotalAmount > 25000 
                             THEN TotalAmount * 0.0005 
                             ELSE 0 
                        END)
FROM Orders 
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SET` or `SELECT` to assign or change the value of a variable.

```
DECLARE @comm decimal(12,2), @amount decimal(12,2) 
SET @comm=0
SELECT @amount=TotalAmount FROM Orders WHERE Id=1

IF @amount>25000
SET @comm=0.0005*@amount;
Else
SET @comm=0


GO

DECLARE @comm decimal(12,2), @amount decimal(12,2) 
SET @comm=0
SELECT @amount=TotalAmount FROM Orders WHERE Id=1

IF @amount>25000
SET @comm=0.0005*@amount;
Else
SET @comm=0
```